# Socket bind failed while configuring apache and renderd

Tags: docker, maps, apache2, openstreetmap, mapnik

I am trying to build a custom map server tile server by following this tutorial on [switch2osm](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-ubuntu-22-04-lts/).

Instead of using ubuntu as described in the tutorial, I am using docker for everything (postgis, apache, etc)

I am trying to build an image where apache and renderd are configured (I followed the instructions found [here](https://github.com/openstreetmap/mod_tile))

Here is my Dockerfile :

```
FROM httpd:2.4

RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y libapache2-mod-tile renderd

 RUN a2enmod tile
 RUN a2enconf renderd

 CMD ["renderd", "-f", "&&", "httpd-foreground"]
```

I keep having this error after building and creating the container :

```
renderd[1]: Initialising unix server socket on /run/renderd/renderd.sock
socket bind failed for: /run/renderd/renderd.sock
```

I know that's a user right issue but I dont see how to fix it.

Please can anyone help me solves this issue ?

Answer (score 3):

I saw the same problem.  I've partially resolved it by changing the owner of /run/renderd via   sudo chown -R osm:osm /run/renderd

Then restarting the renderd process.

I've further tried (and failed) to make this permanent by modifying the file:
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/renderd.service
and specify the user there as well

`[Service] ExecStart=/usr/bin/renderd -f User=osm`

I do believe the above 'fix' has worked in the past, but doesn't seem to work now on Ubuntu 22.04

**An addition to Roger Hellman's answer:**

To make this permanent on Ubuntu 22.04 change the owner  _renderd of /run/renderd   to osm in the file /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/renderd.conf.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
$ sudo mkdir /etc/systemd/system/renderd.service.d/
$ sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/renderd.service.d/custom.conf

[Service]
User=osm
RuntimeDirectory=renderd
```